# RouterLinkActive styling not being applied

Tags: angular, routes, routerlinkactive

I have these options in the nav bar.
[Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDBkw.png)

Since the nav bar background is black, I kept the default font color to be white, and cyan when the route is active.

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
<a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="text-cyan-300" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}" class="m-10 hover:text-slate-300 text-white">Home</a>
<a routerLink="/cars" routerLinkActive="text-cyan-300" class="m-10 hover:text-slate-300 text-white">Cars</a>
```

But the issue is that it is not setting the font color to cyan when the route is active.

On Inspect, I do see that `text-cyan` gets into the class when the route is active.

Class inspect:
[image: class inspect]

But it does not actually show that in the element.

Style getting cancelled:
[image: style getting cancelled]

As a workaround, I wrapped each anchor tag inside separate `div`s and added the default styling there.

But I want to know why my previous approach did not work? What's happening behind the scenes that is preventing the application of `routerLinkActive` styling when the route is active?